# SharePoint Designer 2010 - Send email to multiple users

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a field in a list which needs to take multiple users and an email needs to be sent out to all those users. I picked the field as 'Type of information' being 'Person or Group' and 'Allow multiple selections' being 'Yes'.
I tried a few options like building a dynamic string with the usernames/email ids and storing them in a variable and then using that variable. That didn't help. I don't want to create a group because my users will be different every time. Any suggestions on how can we send email to multiple users other than using a group?

Comment: Can you please elaborate why dynamic string didn't worked, was there any exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

No need to create any dynamic strings.

Based on my experience you create a new variable and read the value in the new Person or Group column into it. SharePoint handles the translation of the names in the column as the e-mail is generated.

Now use the WORKFLOW variable in the TO line of the e-mail.